# Proof that the operator $\Theta\vec{\omega}=-\mu\Delta\vec{\omega}-(\lambda+\mu)\nabla(\nabla\cdot\vec{\omega})$ is positive and self-adjoint

Tags: mathematical-physics, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following partial differential equation (eigenvalue equation)
\begin{equation}
\Theta \vec{\omega}=\alpha\vec{\omega}
\end{equation}
where I have defined the linear partial differential operator $\Theta$ as $$\Theta\vec{\omega}=-\mu\Delta\vec{\omega}-(\lambda+\mu)\nabla(\nabla\cdot\vec{\omega}).$$ I would like to show that this operator is positive self-adjoint with respect to the $L^2$ scalar product $(u,v)=\int_B u^*\cdot v~ d^3 r$. In a paper which I found ([link](http://flyingv.ucsd.edu/papers/PDF/38.pdf), [doi](https://doi.org/10.1093/imamat/65.2.109)) they said it is obvious, however, I would like to prove this explicitly but I struggle a lot. Can anyone give me a hint or some intuition how to prove that? In my case $B$ denotes the body which is a sphere with radius $R$ and $\lambda,\mu$ are the Lamé parameters. This equation one encounters often in linear and isotropic elasticity.

If I could show this, than an immediate consequence would be that the eigenvalues are real and positive as well as the eigenfunctions to different eigenvalues are orthogonal, that is clear an easy to prove if the operator is self-adjoint. Is it also possible to prove that the eigenfunction form a complete set of a basis, so that I can write every vector field defined on $B$ as a linear combination of the eigenfunctions?

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this question?

Answer (score 2):

The operator is self-adjoint trivially by  the spectral theorem. In fact, it can be seen as a real-orthogonal-matrix-valued function $f(-i\nabla)$ of the self-adjoint $-i \nabla$ operator.

If the function $f$ is also positive as a matrix (when considered as a function of a real variable), then the operator is positive.

The resulting operator is however unbounded (if, as I assume, the function is unbounded), and does not have compact resolvent so it does not admit a complete basis of eigenvalues.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean with "trivially by the spectral theorem" and what this function $f$ should be. I tried to prove it explicitly with some vector identities and I'm almost done expect the proof that the Laplacian is self adjoint. The problem is that it should be a complete basis, otherwise it would not be physical.

Comment: @LLanadas The function would be the one that yields acting on a vector $v=(v_1,\dotsc,v_d)$, $(f(k)v)_i=\sum_{j=1}^d \mu k_j^2 v_i +(\lambda+\mu)\sum_{j=1}^d k_ik_jv_j$. One has to check that this matrix valued function is real orthogonal, and thus the resulting operator is self-adjoint (by the spectral theorem, in its functional calculus version). Then, if the matrix function is also pointwise positive (as a matrix), the operator is also positive.

Comment: I have to admit that I can't follow all your arguments (sorry I'm not an expert in functional analysis), but I'll try to follow it. From my point of view it is now clear what do you mean with the function $f$ ($f$ is in my case $\Theta$ an $k=-i\nabla$, right?) , but I have really no idea how to prove all these things  and how to use the spectral theorem, but it seems a very elegant way to proof this. The big problem is that you mentioned that the basis of eigenvectors are  not complete, because my entire theory is based on this assumption.

Comment: @LLanadas. If the Hilbert space spectrum is not pure point, then some of the eigenvectors lie outside of the Hilbert space in a distributional extension called rigged Hilbert space. That is why the "basis of eigenvectors is not complete". The immediate example is the Hamiltonian of the virtual particle of reduced mass in the Schroedinger Hydrogen atom.

Comment: ok, that sounds understandable and familiar to me.....but in my case I think the spectrum is pure point . I  forgot to mention that in my particular exercise I have to examine small displacement  in a sphere, and due to the boundary conditions i get a discrete set (but infinite)  of  "eigenfrequencies". So in this particular case the spectrum seems point like. If it is point like, does the propertie of self-adjointness implie automatically that that the eigenfunctions form a complete set, or how could i prove this fact?

Comment: @yuggib Is it possible to prove the self-adjointness with your proposal without considering particular boundary conditions ?  Because in my case it is not easy (or even not possible) to argue that in the proof below  the  surface integral has to vanish. Is there some book which you  could recommend to me where this kind of proof is explained in detail ?

Comment: It is possible to use the spectral theorem to prove self-adjointness, provided that the operator $-i\nabla$, with a suitable choice of boundary conditions, is self-adjoint (but that should be standard). Concerning the spectral thoerem, you can find it in many classic textbooks of operator theory. I like the presentation in Weidmann's book "Linear operators in Hilbert spaces".

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are constants, you can certainly trace again all the results below if that is not the case. In general you want to study the product

$$
\langle \Theta {\bf f}| {\bf g}\rangle = \langle {\bf f}| \Theta {\bf g}\rangle \tag{1}
$$

let's start by pieces

> $\nabla^2$

First note that

$$
(\nabla^2 {\bf f}^*)\cdot{\bf g} = \nabla\cdot [(\nabla {\bf f}){\bf g}] - \nabla {\bf f} : \nabla {\bf g}
$$

So that

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_\Omega (\nabla^2 {\bf f}^*)\cdot{\bf g} ~{\rm d}^3 {\bf x} &=& \int_\Omega \nabla\cdot [(\nabla {\bf f}^*)\cdot{\bf g}]~ {\rm d}^3 {\bf x} - \int_\Omega\nabla {\bf f}^* : \nabla {\bf g}~{\rm d}^3 {\bf x} \\
&=& \int_{\partial \Omega} [(\nabla {\bf f}^*)\cdot{\bf g}]\cdot {\rm d}^2 {\bf S} - \int_\Omega\nabla {\bf f}^* : \nabla {\bf g}~{\rm d}^3 {\bf x} \\
\end{eqnarray}

The first term vanishes if you assume that both fields vanish at the boundary, or that the flow is normal to the boundary. So you end up with the last  term, and you can apply the same trick again, the result  is

$$
\int_\Omega (\nabla^2 {\bf f}^*)\cdot{\bf g} ~{\rm d}^3 {\bf x} = \int_\Omega {\bf f}^*\cdot(\nabla^2 {\bf g}) ~{\rm d}^3 {\bf x} \tag{2}
$$

> $\nabla (\nabla \cdot)$

You can repeat the same exercise here, the general idea is to express the term as $\nabla \cdot (\text{something}) - \text{stuff}$, use the divergence theorem to get rid of the first term and then process the second term to obtain the final result.

$$
\int_\Omega (\nabla \nabla \cdot{\bf f}^*)\cdot{\bf g} ~{\rm d}^3 {\bf x} = \int_\Omega {\bf f}^*\cdot(\nabla \nabla \cdot{\bf g}) ~{\rm d}^3 {\bf x} \tag{3}
$$

Putting together $(2)$ and $(3)$ you will reach the conclusion in $(1)$, and that's it

Comment: for the second one I got the same result , but my Problem was the surface term which arise in the divergence theorem, or more specifically spoken how to justify that the term vanish, so thats still a open question for me and not so obvious (in my case I have to deal with displacement fields in a sphere). For the Laplacian I did not know these relation , I have never seen this before. It should also be possible to show that these operators are positive, or what do you mean ? ($\lambda$ and $\mu$ are indeed constants)

Comment: But $(\nabla^2 {\bf f}^*)\cdot{\bf g} = \nabla\cdot [(\nabla {\bf f}){\bf g}] - \nabla {\bf f} : \nabla {\bf g}$ is only true if $\nabla\vec{f}=(\nabla\vec{f})^T$

Comment: @LLanadas Depends on your definition of $:$, is it $A_{ij} B_{ij}$ or $A_{ij} B_{ji} $. I used the first, but if you want to use the last one, then you certainly need to add the transpose

Comment: very strange  that this depends on the definition

Comment: In my opinion it is not possible to say that the operator is positive with these kind of proof

Comment: @LLanadas You're right, it only proves it is self-adjoint

Comment: You get in conclusion of the middle stages of above transformations $$⟨Θ\vec f|\vec f⟩=μ\|∇\otimes \vec f\|_{L^2}^2+(λ+μ)\|∇⋅\vec f\|_{L^2}^2$$ which should be sufficient to prove positivity.

Comment: unfortunately there is a minus in  my expression, so it is not obvious that the entire expression is really positiv